# RichTextBox invisible selectable character at end of string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When selecting text in a RichTextBox using the mouse, or arrow keys + shift, I can select an extra blank character at the end of the string.  To reproduce:

- type a few characters (or nothing at all) in a RichTextBox
- set the cursor to the end of the string
- hold shift and press the right arrow key

You'll see a narrow highlighted selection appear, which cannot be deleted.

This causes a problem in my application because the SelectionFont property returns null when the extra character is selected along with some valid text.  Any ideas on how to disable this extra character, or work around it otherwise?

c# winforms, visual studio 2010

Comment: Is it an actual character? As in, if you take the entire string and trim the end off it (or substring-1), is it there?

Comment: I don't think it's an actual character.  If I look at the properties of the RichTextBox when only the extra character is selected, SelectedText returns an empty string, SelectionLength is 0, SelectionType is 'Empty'.  Also, the TextLength property of the RichTextBox does not include this extra character.

Answer (score 0):

FIred up a new winforms app in studio 2010 and wasn't really able to reproduce this. I can select the invisible 'character' but it doesn't cause me any problems. SelectedFont still returns a valid object for me. I can get the text without issue.

Comment: As mentioned above, the 'extra character' seems not to be an actual character, just a UI artifact related to the RichTextBox control. I don't think string manipulation is going to accomplish anything here.

Comment: I suppose I don't understand what you're doing then. I assumed you were getting the value from the textbox and had the ability to verify it for correctness.

Comment: He's not having trouble about the value of the selected "text", but about its font.

Answer (score 0):

**Interesting.** (This is *not* Dr House, MD, speaking.)

When nothing is selected in an empty RTF edit control, `SelectedRtf` returns:

```
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2055\uc1 }"
```

When the "phantom" stuff is selected in the empty RTF edit control, `SelectedRtf` returns:

```
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2055{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17\par
}"
```

Of course, `SelectedText` returns the empty string in both cases.

So I suspect **what is selected is the metainfo that makes sure that newly entered text that would replace the empty selection will be inserted with the correct font**.

However, that seems to be nonsense since newly entered text will be inserted with the correct font even if nothing is selected.

So all that does not make sense. (Well, it does, kind of -- see last paragraph)

**Which makes me believe this is a bug, or at least a glitch, in RichTextBox.**

The formatting info is probably created by the selection routine which makes sure that selected non-empty text will be replaced by the newly typed text formatted in the same format as the text it replaces. For this to work, a selection must always contain the formatting info, even if no text is selected. I think. Maybe one can pre-select a char and paragraph formatting different from the default one, somehow, and then typing text uses that format.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectionFont` property for the `RichTextBox` control can ONLY return a single font.  If the selected range contains more than one font, reading the `SelectionFont` property will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Most likely what is happening is that the `RichTextBox` `Font` property is different than the current font you are using on the selected range.  That "extra" character selected at the end is your `Font` property, not your `SelectionFont` property.

If your `RichTextBox` is just using a single font, just make sure the `Font` and `SelectionFont` property are the same.

Otherwise, just check if it's null:

```
if (richTextBox1.SelectionFont != null) {
  //do something
}
```